# RTC WEB-Browsers (Video and Audio)

Tags: asp.net, node.js, webrtc, videochat, simplewebrtc

Good morning,

I need your help please!

I have a website realized in .Net environment (ASP.NET MVC) and I need to implement inside it a new function: an RTC Web to allow my users to be able to create a web conference with video, audio and chat.

BUT the most important thing is that the entire conference (audio and video) is **to be recorded on the server**!

Do you think is possible to create something like that?

The ideal environment would be .Net but I'm also ready to change the development environment (NodeJs or PHP) to find some solution!

SUMM:

(1) User A join in the chatroom -> (2) Starts video and audio and waits for another user -> (3) User B join in the same chatroom and starts video and audio and starts conversation -> (4) Meanwhile, the server registers the conversation.

What do you recommend me? 
It also needs some simple solution, it does not have to be complicated!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To record on the server side you'll need to add a WebRTC Media Server into the mix. Those that I know aren't built using .net.

Look at [Kurento](https://www.kurento.org/), [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) or [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) for open source alternatives.
They all have the ability to record.